# SQL-Oracle Interrogation

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, max

I have two tables. It's about chess game and it's players.

In the first table I have the details about the player.
In the second table I have the details about the game (player 1, player 2) , (game type).

The two tables are linked together.(Two refferences, player 1 linked with id from first table, player 2 again linked with id from first table)

My task is to do this interrogation.

I have to display, the player with most games played.

The problem is that i have this player in two tables. 
So far I managed to display the maximum of games played by a player from a single column:

```
select Player1,count(Player1) as number_ofgames
group by Player1 
having count(Player 1) in 
(select max(count(Player 1)) from games group by Player1);
```

Comment: So on the column Player1 I have the ID of the player wich can appear on the column Player2 too. Practically I need to count wich ID has the most appearances..I repeat..I managed to do this for column Player 1...but how can I do for both columns ? Because an ID can appear in the other column too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about your table structures therefore assuming your `player` table has column `player_id` as well as `game` table `player1_id` and `player2_id` this query may met your requirements on Oracle 12c.

```
select
    p.player_id,
    count(*) as games_played

from
    player p join game g on p.player_id = g.player1_id or p.player_id = g.player2_id

group by
    p.player_id

order by
    2 desc

fetch first 1 rows with ties;
```

Using the `WITH TIES` clause may result in more rows being returned if multiple rows match the value of the Nth row.

For more details read http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php#top-n.

In MySQL use `LIMIT` instead:

```
select
    p.player_id,
    count(*) as games_played

from
    player p join game g on p.player_id = g.player1_id or p.player_id = g.player2_id

group by
    p.player_id

order by
    2 desc

limit 1;
```

Read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

Comment: Thanks mate ! It works, but it will display all the player's id and games played. How can I display just the player with the most games

Comment: On which DBMS are you on? You've tagged both Oracle and MySQL. Have you included the `LIMIT` or `FETCH FIRST` clause? There are more solutions possible, but those two should work...

Comment: One more question (and sorry for bothering so much): I know how to display the player with most wins...but i need to display winners from different age categories. In my player table, I have a field "birth" DATE type. And i need an interrogation where i can display the winning player for example an alias column "Age between 18-25" to display the best player (with most wins)..then another alias column "Age between 26-30" and so on

Comment: Hit return to early? I can't see your question... Oh now I can see it, sorry.

Comment: That's too complex to answer in a comment and we shouldn't overload this question. The rules for SO say "Ask one question at one time". Sorry. You may try it, show your effort and when you're stuck link a new question in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 11G R2, you could use listagg function.
If not, it will be easy to find a different way

```
   With distrib as
                (select O as dabegin, 17 as daend, 'under 18' as category from dual
                union all 
                select 18 as dabegin ,25 as daend, 'between 18-25' as category from dual
                union all 
                select 26 as dabegin ,30 as daend,  'between 26-30' as category from dual
                 )
                , games as
                (select
                    p.player_id,
                    count(*) as games_played

    from
        player p join game g on p.player_id = g.player1_id or p.player_id = g.player2_id

group by
    p.player_id)
select max(games_played), listagg(player_id,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY player_id) as 'winner(s)', category
from distrib d, games g, players p
where p.player_id=g.player_id
and g. age between d.dabegin and daend
group by g.category
```